# Trying to modify the Auth registration system in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to modify the Authentication system in Laravel.  What I'm trying to do is add in a drop down list so first time users can select a country that they live in.  How every, when I add in the drop down list and click the register button I get this error:

```
 QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Mandy, mandy@NBDC.com, $2y$10$2kC1tOr91OTy1y6VrtoupuwjhXQI7kKnE.N19aAG1uQOKnXwrR3dG, 2016-09-29 22:26:45, 2016-09-29 22:26:45))
```

To try can work around this, I tried to overrider the register method in the RegisterController.  With the code that I added, it adds the user to the database, but it does not Authorize the User in anyway.  Or instance, I redirect to the default home page that the Auth system comes with, but since the user is not logged in, it redirects to the login page.

I was just wondering if anyone out there has make any such modifications to the Auth system such as this, and if you can clue me in one what to do.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and not clear enough to detect what you are really trying to achieve. If you are willing to add the country Id to your user table you need also to pass the selected value coming from the drop down box to the query.

Comment: @Franco So that is what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  The route list says the action going to the register method on the RegisterController, but when you look at that, that method isn't list.  I've looked around, but just can't find where that method is so that I can add it in.  so that is what I was seeking help for.

Comment: you even donot have country field in users table.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is authentication and not authorization. The `register()` method is provided by the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait which is used by `RegisterController`. It does the user authentication upon registration in this line:

```
$this->guard()->login($this->create($request->all()));
```

`$request->all()` is passed to `$this->create()` which returns a newly created `User` instance which is then passed to `$this->guard()->login()`.

To answer your question, you must override the `create()` method in your `RegisterController` to include `country_id` and make sure to return a `User` instance. You probably need to update the `validator()` method too to validate `country_id`.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'country_id' => 'required', // add validation rule
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'country_id' => $data['country_id'], // include country_id
    ]);
}
```

Make sure you update your `User` model's `$fillable` property to include `country_id`.

Comment: So I tried that, but it didn't work.  I get this error:QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (James, James@gmail.com, $2y$10$2pkY63OJB20fRI7gDietsurJ2NKpIQaWSoqGgI2JMVUGX4oo7MMay, 2016-09-30 12:12:13, 2016-09-30 12:12:13))

Answer (score 0):

Ok it did work.  What was missing was that I miss spelled the country_id name,  It was set to country and not country_id within the create method.  I think I over looked that during the massive coding I was doing.  Thanks for the help.